# не могу присоединить и отправить аттач с формы

Tags: php

Есть форма, вот код:

```
<div class="form-container">
<h2>Для подачи заявления, заполните пожалуйста форму</h2>
<form id="feedback-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="http://zayavlenie.com.ua/send.php">
    <input type="text" class="name" name="name" placeholder="Ваше ФИО" required="">
    <input type="text" class="adress" name="adress" placeholder="Ваш адрес, куда доставляли двери" required="">
    <input type="phone" class="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required="">
    <p>№ счёт-фактуры и дата</p>
    <input type="text" class="name-f" name="name_f" placeholder="например: ДБ 000001450 от 03.08.2018" required="">
    <p class="shop-title">Магазин</p>
    <p class="dev-descr">Выберите магазин, в котором Вы оформляли заказ</p>
    <select name="shop" class="shop" data-tilda-req="1" style="color:#000000; border:1px solid #a8a8a8;" required="">
        <option value="">Выберите вариант из списка...</option>
        <option value="Киев, пр. Победы, 17">Киев, пр. Победы, 17</option>
        <option value="Киев, ул. Большая Васильковская, 145/1">Киев, ул. Большая Васильковская, 145/1</option>
        <option value="Киев, Демеевская площадь, пр. В. Лобановского">Киев, Демеевская площадь, пр. В. Лобановского</option>
        <option value="Киев, ул. Кольцевая, 2">Киев, ул. Кольцевая, 2</option>
        <option value="Киев, ул. Марины Цветаевой, 13">Киев, ул. Марины Цветаевой, 13</option>
        <option value="Киев, ул. Днепровская Набережная, 26-Д">Киев, ул. Днепровская Набережная, 26-Д</option>
        <option value="Киев, пр. Голосеевский, 128">Киев, пр. Голосеевский, 128</option>
        <option value="Киев, бул. Чоколовский, 9/13">Киев, бул. Чоколовский, 9/13</option>
        <option value="Киев, ул. Харьковское Шоссе, 2  ">Киев, ул. Харьковское Шоссе, 2</option>
        <option value="Киев, пр. Героев Сталинграда, 6">Киев, пр. Героев Сталинграда, 6</option>
        <option value="Львов, ул. Научная, 49-А">Львов, ул. Научная, 49-А</option>
        <option value="Львов, ул. Липинского, 28 (Парус)">Львов, ул. Липинского, 28 (Парус)</option>
        <option value="Львов, ул. Городоцкая, 209">Львов, ул. Городоцкая, 209</option>
        <option value="Днепр, ул. Литейная, 17-А">Днепр, ул. Литейная, 17-А</option>
        <option value="Днепр, пр. Гагарина, 99">Днепр, пр. Гагарина, 99</option>
        <option value="Днепр, ул. Сечевых Стрельцов, 89-Б (ул. Артёма)">Днепр, ул. Сечевых Стрельцов, 89-Б (ул. Артёма)</option>
        <option value="Днепр, пр. Слобожанский, 107 (им. Газеты Правда)">Днепр, пр. Слобожанский, 107 (им. Газеты Правда)</option>
        <option value="Одесса, пр. Небесной Сотни, 3-А (пр. Маршала Жукова) ">Одесса, пр. Небесной Сотни, 3-А (пр. Маршала Жукова) </option>
        <option value="Одесса, ул. Николаевская дорога, 223/225">Одесса, ул. Николаевская дорога, 223/225</option>
        <option value="Одесса, ул. Малая Арнаутская, 92">Одесса, ул. Малая Арнаутская, 92</option>
        <option value="Харьков, пр. Гагарина, 21">Харьков, пр. Гагарина, 21</option>
        <option value="Харьков, ул. Героев Труда, 46">Харьков, ул. Героев Труда, 46</option>
    </select>
    <p>Название товара</p>
    <p class="dev-descr">Введите название двери или фурнитуры, по которому Вы хотите произвести обмен или возврат.</p>
    <input type="text" class="tovar" name="tovar" placeholder="Например: Вена орех ПО" required="">
    <p>Кем был произведен замер?</p>
    <select name="master" class="master" style="color:#000000; border:1px solid #a8a8a8;" required="">
        <option value="">Выберите вариант из списка...</option>
        <option value="Мастерами Двери Белоруссии">Мастерами Двери Белоруссии</option>
        <option value="У меня был свой мастер">У меня был свой мастер</option>
    </select>
    <p>Кем была произведена установка?</p>
    <select name="install_w" class="t-select js-tilda-rule " data-tilda-req="1" style="color:#000000; border:1px solid #a8a8a8;" required="">
        <option value="">Выберите вариант из списка...</option>
        <option value="Мастерами Двери Белоруссии">Мастерами Двери Белоруссии</option>
        <option value="У меня был свой мастер">У меня был свой мастер</option>
    </select>
    <textarea class="brak" name="brak" placeholder="Опишите Ваш брак или причину замены." required=""></textarea>
    <div class="input-file-container">
        <p>Загрузить фото</p>
        <label class="input-file" for="file">
            <span>Выбрать файл:</span>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="file">
        </label>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="patch_file" id="patch_file" disabled="" class="patch-file">
    <p>Выберите подходящие решение:</p>
    <select name="select" class="t-select js-tilda-rule " data-tilda-req="1" style="color:#000000; border:1px solid #a8a8a8;" required="">
        <option value="1. Замена товара (при браке товара или если товар Вам не подошел)">1. Замена товара (при браке товара или если товар Вам не подошел)</option>
        <option value="2. Возврат средств (при браке товара)">2. Возврат средств (при браке товара)</option>
        <option value="3. Вызвать реставратора (при мелком браке)">3. Вызвать реставратора (при мелком браке)</option>
        <option value="4. Вызвать установщика (при браке установки)">4. Вызвать установщика (при браке установки)</option>
        <option value="5. Узнать у менеджера (узнать подходящий для меня вариант)">5. Узнать у менеджера (узнать подходящий для меня вариант)</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="t-submit" style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#000000;">ОТПРАВИТЬ ЗАЯВЛЕНИЕ</button>
</form>
```

С нее данные принимаются и обрабатываются этим скриптом (код ниже). Цель - отправить на почту шаблон в html(обязательно) с аттачем, если он есть.
Внес новый код скрипта: проблема в том что теперь приходит письмо, с иконкой вложения но самого вложения нет

Ещё одно условие - только дефолтный mail

Код скрипта:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$headers  .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
// $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
// $boundary = md5(date('r', time()));
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');
$name = $_POST[name];
$adress = $_POST[adress];
$phone = $_POST[phone];
$faktura = $_POST[name_f];
$tovar = $_POST[tovar];
$shop = $_POST[shop];
$master = $_POST[master];
$install = $_POST[install_w];
$brak = $_POST[brak];
$file = $_POST[file];
$link = $_POST[Загрузить_файл];
$select = $_POST[select];
// print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
switch ($shop) {
            case "Киев, пр. Победы, 17":
                $test_mail = "magazin2@dveribelorussii.com";
                break;
           case "Киев, ул. Большая Васильковская, 145/1":
               $test_mail = "magazin1@dveribelorussii.com";
               break;
           case "Киев, Демеевская площадь, пр. В. Лобановского":
               $test_mail = "magazin11@dveribelorussii.com";
           break;
           case "Киев, ул. Кольцевая, 2":
               $test_mail = "magazin10@dveribelorussii.com";
           break;
           case "Киев, ул. Марины Цветаевой, 13":
               $test_mail = "magazin9@dveribelorussii.com";
           break;
           case "Киев, ул. Днепровская Набережная, 26-Д":
               $test_mail = "magazin8@dveribelorussii.com";
           break;
           case "Киев, пр. Голосеевский, 128":
               $test_mail = "magazin6@dveribelorussii.com";
           break;
           case "Киев, бул. Чоколовский, 9/13":
               $test_mail = "magazin5@dveribelorussii.com";
           break;
           case "Киев, ул. Харьковское Шоссе, 2":
               $test_mail = "magazin4@dveribelorussii.com";
           break;
           case "Львов, ул. Научная, 49-А":
               $test_mail = "dverihorod@ukr.net";
           break;
           case "Львов, ул. Липинского, 28 (Парус)":
               $test_mail = "dverihorod@ukr.net";
           break;
           case "Львов, ул. Городоцкая, 209":
               $test_mail = "dverihorod@ukr.net";
           break;
           case "Днепр, ул. Литейная, 17-А":
               $test_mail = "lux-dnepr@ukr.net    ";
           break;
           case "Днепр, пр. Гагарина, 99":
               $test_mail = "dveri.gagarina@ukr.net ";
           break;
           case "Днепр, ул. Сечевых Стрельцов, 89-Б (ул. Артёма)":
               $test_mail = "dveribel@ukr.net";
           break;
           case "Днепр, пр. Слобожанский, 107 (им. Газеты Правда)":
               $test_mail = "pravda.magazin@ukr.net ";
           break;
           case "Одесса, пр. Небесной Сотни, 3-А (пр. Маршала Жукова)":
               $test_mail = "diana.serba.ds@gmail.com";
           break;
           case "Одесса, ул. Николаевская дорога, 223/225":
               $test_mail = "diana.serba.ds@gmail.com";
           break;
           case "Одесса, ул. Малая Арнаутская, 92":
               $test_mail = "diana.serba.ds@gmail.com";
           break;
           case "Харьков, пр. Гагарина, 21":
               $test_mail = "roznh@dveribelorussii.com";
           break;
           case "Харьков, ул. Героев Труда, 46":
               $test_mail = "roznh@dveribelorussii.com";
           break;
           default:
               $test_mail = "Ты лажанулся";
        }
    $date = strftime('%A %d %B %G');
$message = '
    <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="black">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" height="75">
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%" align="left" vertical-align="bottom">
                        <b>&nbsp;Заявление от:&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$date.'</b>
                    </td>
                    <td width="50%">
                        <img src="https://dveribelorussii.com.ua/local/templates/standart/images/icons/new-dveribel-ru.svg" width="133" height="70" align="right">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" height="15">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" color="red" bgcolor="#e3e4e5">
                        <b>&nbsp;Информация о клиенте:</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
        <td width="100%" align="left">
            <b>&nbsp;ФИО:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>'.$name.'</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
        <td width="100%" align="left">
            <b>&nbsp;Адрес:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>'.$adress.'</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
        <td width="100%" align="left">
            <b>&nbsp;Телефон:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>'.$phone.'</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
        <td width="100%" align="left">
            <b>&nbsp;Магазин:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>'.$shop.'</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" height="15">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" color="red" bgcolor="#e3e4e5">
                        <b>&nbsp;Информация о клиенте:</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
        <td width="100%" align="left">
            <b>&nbsp;№ СФ и дата:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>'.$faktura.'</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
        <td width="100%" align="left">
            <b>&nbsp;№ РН и дата:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>________________________</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
        <td width="100%" align="left">
            <b>&nbsp;Наименование товара:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>'.$tovar.'</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
        <td width="100%" align="left">
            <b>&nbsp;Кем был произведён замер:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>'.$master.'</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
        <td width="100%" align="left">
            <b>&nbsp;Кем была произведёна установка:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>'.$install.'</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" height="15">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" color="red" bgcolor="#e3e4e5">
                        <b>&nbsp;Описание брака или причина замены:</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="100">
        <td width="100%" align="left">
            &nbsp;<span>'.$brak.'</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="25">
        <td width="100%" align="left" bgcolor="#e3e4e5">
            <b>&nbsp;Необходимые действия:</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr width="100%" height="30">
        <td width="100%" height="30">
            &nbsp;<span>'.$select.'</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr width="100%" height="30">
        <td width="100%" height="30">
            &nbsp;<b>Ваше вложение</b><br><a href="http://zayavlenie.com.ua/'.$uploadfile.'"download="">Скачать</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>';
$uploaddir = './upload_files/';
$senddir ='./send_files';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
if (copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
{
echo "<h3>Файл успешно загружен на сервер</h3>";
}
else { echo "<h3>Ошибка! Не удалось загрузить файл на сервер!</h3>"; exit; }
move_uploaded_file($uploadfile, $senddir);
$uploadfile = $senddir.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$uploadfile = (print_r($uploadfile));
echo('<br><a href="http://zayavlenie.com.ua/'.$uploadfile.'" download="">Скачать</a>');


is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
          $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])));
          $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
          $filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
          echo("дошли");
         die();
          $message.="

 --$boundary
 Content-Type: \"$filetype\"; name=\"$filename\"
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"

 $attachment";
  $message.="
 --$boundary--";
$to = "webazex@gmail.com";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

?>

Comment: И где в этом коде отправляется аттач?

Comment: уже поправил скрипт, добавил код аттача

Comment: Что логи говорят насчёт ошибки 500 ?

Comment: а где его найти?

Comment: Не нужно писать так `$_POST[name]` - во первых нотис, а во вторых будет предупреждение о том, что константа `name` не найдена, пишите в `$_POST['name']`  в одинарных или двойных кавычках и проверяйте через `isset`, а лучше всего использовать функцию `filter_input`.

Comment: @u_mulder перезалил код.